# What is causing a "word not bound to context" error in this script?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

I have the following R3-GUI script:

```
Rebol [
    file: %context.reb
]

either exists? %r3-gui.r3 [do %r3-gui.r3][load-gui]

view [
    title "First Window"
    hgroup [
        lab: label "fld 1 "
        fld1: field "Field Data 1"
    ]
    button "Display fld 1" on-action [if error? try [probe get-face fld1][alert "Can't read fld1"]]
    button "Display fld 2" on-action [if error? try [probe get-face fld2][alert "Can't read fld2"]]
    button "Open 2nd Window" on-action [
        view [
            title "Second Window"
            hgroup [
                label "fld 2" fld2: field "field 2 data"
            ]
            button "Display fld1" on-action [if error? err: try [probe get-face fld1][probe err alert "Can't read fld1"]]
            button "Display fld2" on-action [if error? err: try [probe get-face fld2][probe err alert "Can't read fld2" ]]
        ]
    ]
]
```

When I click on the "Display fld2" button in the 2nd window to access the contents of fld2, I am getting a `** Script error: fld2 word is not bound to a context` error. What is the cause of this? And how do I access the `fld2` word inside the second window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is arising because the anonymous function that is being created by the `parse-layout` function should be a closure, and it isn't.  See the diff at https://gist.github.com/earl/a009454787d9fe4cfaca which fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

because fld2 is local to an anonymous function and not bound to the user context

```
>> help win-face/facets/tab-face/actors 
WIN-FACE/FACETS/TAB-FACE/ACTORS is a block of value: [on-action make function! [[face arg
        /local fld2 err
    ][
        view layout [
            title "Second Window"
            hgroup [
                label "fld 2" fld2: field "field 2 data"
            ]
            button "Display fld 1" on-action [if error? try [probe get-face fld1] [alert "Can't read fld1"]]
            button "Display fld2" on-action [if error? err: try [probe get-face fld2] [probe err alert "Can't read fld2"]]
        ]
    ]]]
>>
```

it works, if you do it this way

```
 l2: layout [
    title "Second Window"
    hgroup [
       label "fld 2" fld2: field "field 2 data"
    ]
    button "Display fld1" on-action [if error? err: try [probe get-face fld1][probe err alert "Can't read fld1"]]
    button "Display fld2" on-action [if error? err: try [probe get-face fld2][probe err alert "Can't read fld2" ]]
]


view  l1: layout [
   title "First Window"
   hgroup [
       lab: label "fld 1 "
       fld1: field "Field Data 1"
   ]
   button "Display fld 1" on-action [if error? try [probe get-face fld1][alert "Can't read fld1"]]
   button "Display fld 2" on-action [if error? try [probe get-face fld2][alert "Can't read fld2"]]
   button "Open 2nd Window" on-action [
      view l2
   ]
]
```

Comment: Works but if you close Window 2 down, and then open it again, Rebol 3 crashes!  :(

Comment: no crash with 32 bit Windows, but with 64 bit Linux

Comment: Tried it again.  Open 2nd window, close it, open it again, and the screen contents are incorrect until you resize the window or move it. On Win32.

Comment: I used r3-32-view-2014-02-14-1926d8.exe and I can not confirm that